# How to create double-clickable .exe on Windows that is ssh command

Tags: windows, ssh

On OSX, I've used the Automator application to send iTerm an ssh user@host "remote command" command and save it as a .app that's double-clickable--how would I do the equivalent on Windows XP/Vista/7?

Comment: A better explanation may help non-Mac persons. I am not a Mac.

Comment: You probably don't need an .exe but just a sortcut with right parameters to some ssh program - like garyjohn suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have an ssh client on your Windows machine, open Windows Explorer (the Windows file manager), navigate to the directory containing your ssh.exe, right click on ssh.exe and select `Send To` -> `Desktop (create shortcut)`. Then, on your Desktop, right click on the shortcut (it will be named "shortcut to ssh.exe"--you can rename it to anything you like) and select `Properties`. Click on the `Shortcut` tab if that one isn't already selected. In the `Target:` field will be the full path to your ssh.exe. Simply add any arguments after the command as you would on the command line. Click `OK`.

Now you can double click the shortcut and your ssh command will be executed. If you don't have to enter a password and don't want to see the Command Prompt window, open the shortcut's `Properties` dialog again, select the `Shortcut` tab, and in the `Run:` field, select "Minimized".

That's all for Windows XP.

For an ssh client, I use the one from [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), but Cygwin is probably too much if all you want is ssh.

Answer (score 1):

[PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) is a good Windows-based SSH client.  I've used it on XP.  The FAQ includes [an answer](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/faq.html#faq-startsess) to this question.  It's along the same lines as garyjohn's answer.